# How would one go about populating a newsfeed with post as shown in picture below with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am running on rails version 4.2.2 and Ruby 2.2.3

When a user clicks on one of the smaller picture. I would like the database to call the larger version of the picture saved within that project.

Preview of picture

[Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfaTl.png)

Comment: You probably have ideas already on how this feature might be implemented, so you should make an attempt to code it and then post when you have specific questions about any problems you encounter. As stated, your question is (at best) a request for design assistance or (at worst) a request for someone to provide code, both of which are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see the [SO Help file](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: I have a few ideas on how to implement it but I just don't know the right questions to ask. I am not asking for the code, I am asking for someone to point me in the right direction on how to go this particular issue. A link or anything is helpful. I have about 7 months of experience working with rails.

Comment: 7 months and you can't even figure out the basic gist of a slideshow? What have you been doing?

Comment: 7 months included HTML CSS and JavaScript learning.  Then I picked up ruby on rails to see how it all fits in order to build my application. I can follow the MVC model. I just don't know how to implement it. My approach was to generate  a migration in order  create a column for the picture that are going to be posted in post model. I just can't wrap my head around how am I going to implement that in the view. I can tell the controller to grab some specific picture but not all of them as they are being uploaded.

Comment: Try to do the uploading and rendering of images first, then use can easily achieved the viewing of large image when clicked on small one, using JQUERY. Simply change the image url of the large one based on clicked image.

Comment: When you do the uploading of image in RAILS, you can set different sizes of if leaving the original size. So you can change the image src/url like /images/user/1/original/sample.png